# pyodbc unicode query fails

Tags: python, unicode, pyodbc, vertica

I'm using pyodbc to connect to Vertica.
I've installed Vertica driver, unixodbc and pyodbc.

Now I have problem with executinq unicode queries.

```
con = pyodbc.connect('Driver={driver};Servername={server};Port={port};Database={db};UserName={user};password={password}'.format(...))
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute('SELECT * FROM table')  # It works
cur.execute(u'SELECT * FROM table')  # It fails
```

The error is:

```
ProgrammingError: ('42601', '[42601] ERROR 4856:  Syntax error at or near " (4856) (SQLExecDirectW)')
```

Comment: Looks like this driver needs an encoded string instead of a unicode one.

Comment: Have you tried to `.encode('utf-8')`?

Comment: yes @woot, I tried, but it didn't work

Comment: @user1263702 Sorry I don't have an answer for you... I've had all sorts of unicode issues with unixodbc myself.  I switched to vertica_python written by Uber. (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/vertica-python/0.3.0)  You'll want to read the docs though about how to do bind parameters (need to compile postgresql libs if I remember correctly).

Answer (score 1):

Looks like wrong encoding defined in `vertica.ini` file(or wrong `locale` setting in `odbc.ini`)

### `vertica.ini`

```
[Driver]
DriverManagerEncoding=UTF-16
...
```

### `odbc.ini`

```
...
Locale                      = en_US@collation=binary
...
```

I bet on `vertica.ini`. I have no MacOS to check, but by docs you need to define `UTF-32`. Can you post your `vertica.ini` abd `odbc.ini` + database locale?

### HP Vertica

```
daniel=> show locale;
  name  |               setting            
--------+--------------------------------------
 locale | en_US@collation=binary (LEN_KBINARY)
(1 row)
```

---

For more info read [here](http://my.vertica.com/docs/7.1.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/ConnectingToHPVertica/ClientODBC/AdditionalParameterSettings.htm).

Answer (score 0):

What version of pyodbc and python you are using? What OS?

try using first line in your python code as # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-?

and update pyodbc
sudo pip install --upgrade pyodbc

Comment: I'm using python 2.7.5 on mac os x 10.9.4 with pyodbc 3.0.7